# Не работает nextLine() у Scanner`а

Tags: java, scanner

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

// Владелец
System.out.print("Владелец: ");
String owner = sc.nextLine();
// Номер парковки
System.out.print("Номер парковки: ");
String number = sc.nextLine();
```

Я должен ввести значение для owner и number строки, но в консоль выводит:

```
Владелец: Номер парковки: АЕ-535

--- Вы ввели ---
Владелец:
Номер парковки: АЕ-535
```

и я могу ввести значение. но это значение будет только для number.
Как тогда быть?

Comment: У меня все работает) Можете [полный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) привести? Или уточнить где и как запускаете?

Comment: Попробуйте вывести  слово "Владелец" с переходом на новую строку `System.out.println` или заменить `nextLine` на `next`

Answer (score 2):

Все работает. Нужно только правильно и внимательно использовать.
Значения в данном примере вводятся с клавиатуры поочередно как для owner, так и для number. Скорее всего для значения owner был нажат просто Enter и значением для owner была задана пустая строка (а-ля String owner = ""), поэтому и значение для него не вывелось в консоль.
Обратите внимание, что System.out.print() выводит данные в консоль в одну строку, а System.out.println() - с новой строки.
Символ \n внутри текста также обеспечивает вывод текста с новой строки.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Владелец: ");
    String owner = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Номер парковки: ");
    String number = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print ("Владелец: " + owner + " ");
    System.out.print ("Номер парковки: " + number);
    System.out.println ();
    System.out.println ("Владелец: " + owner);
    System.out.println ("Номер парковки: " + number);
    System.out.println ("Альтернативный вариант: \nВладелец: " + owner + "\nНомер парковки: " + number );
    sc.close();
}
Console:
Владелец: Я
Номер парковки: 1
Владелец: Я Номер парковки: 1
Владелец: Я
Номер парковки: 1
Альтернативный вариант: 
Владелец: Я
Номер парковки: 1
```